# Is it possible to receive SMS notification inside an app in IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sms

Consider 2 iOS phones running an app. 
The app in one phone sends a SMS to the other phone. I want to know two things.

1. Is it possible to show a notification inside the same app in second phone when this SMS is received.
2. Is it possible to receive this SMS only inside the app ie, this SMS should not go to the default iOS message inbox.

Comment: The only way to do this would be to make your own custom notification by some type of server communication.  Just make a look-alike of an SMS notification show up and trigger it with some backend service.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's absolutely not possible without jailbreak.
iOS does not provide any public API to deal with SMS without going through the `MFMessageComposeViewController`.